# Adding error message on button click in Asp.net Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having an issue with using error message in ASP.net mvc. When the user clicks save even nothing wasn't entered it still redirects them to another page but I would like to give them an error if no information was entered. I want it to be done on the client side. This what I have thus far

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Finish(Student model, string finish)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.error("No item was entered");
           return View(getStudent);
        }

        else (string.IsNullOrEmpty(finish))
        {
            //redirects to student record page when finish is clicked
            return RedirectToAction("StudentRecord");
        }

    }
```

where in here would put the error message

```
 <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-12"> <input type="button" value="Finish" name="Issue" margin="50px" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ViewIssue","Issue")' " class="btn btn-default" /> </div>
```

Comment: Can you add your markup

Comment: Could you show Student class?

Comment: You should use `DataAttributes` on your `Student` model and let asp.net handle the validation for you.

Comment: I handled the data attributes already. I want to add the validation based on if the user enter a student record. so if the user enters a student record it directs to another page but if there's no student record entered then they'll get an error

Comment: `ViewBag.error("No item was entered");` => it should be `ViewBag.Error = "No item was entered";` and use `@ViewBag.Error` inside CSHTML file you want to add the message. Or you can take `RequiredAttribute` with error message & use `Html.ValidationMessageFor` to display it.

Comment: could you give me an example within the cshtml file. this is button I have     <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-12">

                
                    <input type="button" value="Finish" name="Issue" margin="50px" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ViewIssue","Issue")' " class="btn btn-default" />
                    


                </div>

Comment: Can u please put the above HTML in the question by clicking edit

Comment: I have edited the question with the html. Can you assist me please

Comment: Hey Tetsuya is it possible to show me an example

Answer (score 0):

Set your View to display a TempData, which works the same as a ViewBag, but persists its data through redirects, in case your Model.IsValid condition fail. Also, put a try/catch statement inside the if condition just in case too.
Also also, I recommend you return to your original View in case the user fills in the form wrong somehow, so he can fix whatever it was.

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Finish([Bind(Include = "propertyName1,propertyName2,propertyName3")] Student model, string finish)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try {
            //do your logic here
            return RedirectToAction("StudentRecord");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            TempData["errorMessage"] = "Error: " + ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException;
            //ViewBag.errorMessage = "Error: " + ex.Message + " - " + ex.InnerException;
            return View(model);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["errorMessage"] = "Error: Please fill the form correctly";
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then in your View:

```
@model your_domain.Student

<span>
    @TempData["errorMessage"]
    //@ViewBag.errorMessage
</span>
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I don't seem to be getting an output it just redirects to the other page

Comment: @bujulloyd Notice that the Action is supposed to do any logic at all only when the ModelState is valid. I reversed your original logic order and set the else, aka when ModelState is ~not~ valid to store a error message, which will show in your View later.

Comment: @bujulloyd If you did write your action the way I proposed and you're just getting redirected, then it means the object was filled correctly, so there would be no need for a error message indeed.

Comment: it wasn't completed

Comment: Oh wait perhaps I should remove this onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ViewIssue",

Comment: Maybe the property you didn't fill is a nullable type. Did you check if it was? If you really need a property to be required for the object, change the "Student model" according to my update, binding the properties you have in your View to the Student object the Action is expecting.

Comment: @bujulloyd You don't need that button at all anymore. Just put a submit button in your View. The error message will be displayed elsewhere, in the `<span>` tag I suggested.

Comment: Look at my answer.